# How can you have multiple methods that use a single @Override method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm using Slick2D which provides a single render method which is used to draw graphics. Is there a way I can create multiple render methods that serve different purposes (One to draw rectangles, One to draw strings...)?

```
@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    //What works
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.drawString("Hello World", 0, 0);

    //What I wish I could do
    public void drawRect (int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    public void drawString (int x, int y, String text) {
        g.drawString (text, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you cannot. The render method is defined in the interface you have implemented. And there can be only one implementation of it its implementing class.

Comment: short answer would be no, your render method I guess is being defined in an interface or parent class.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that but what you can do is:

```
public void render(Graphics g)  {
      g.draw.....
}



@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    render(g);
}
```

The reason is firstly render method is defined in some class of slick which you are implementing or extending. You cannot use @Override annotation unless you are overriding the method.
Overriding means defining a method again of the superclass.

What I have shown you is called overloading. You are having method with same names but different parameters.